# Vista monitor Display Setting default 2-1?

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors, display-settings

I run a Sony HDTV to my VAIO laptop video and audio, works fine.  Except it defaults to monitor order of 1-2 and resets after every boot or profound desktop change.

Can a Registry tweak be set to change the order to 2-1?

Answer (score 0):

I found this. It seems logical. Credit goes to Fleece per this [thread](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-general/81095-changing-monitor-identities-2.html)....

---

> My solution to this problem was to set this registry key carefully to value of "0" (zero)...
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\TMM\UseIviewHelper
>
> ..., next fully uninstall the NVIDIA drivers and control software, and reboot with only the primary and desired #1 monitor connected. That reset the #2 monitor as #1 monitor. Then, reinstall the NVIDIA drivers and control software and setup second monitor. Problem solved.
>
> Credit goes to this external forum post...
> [Dual Display Numbering in Vista](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistaappearance/thread/1aa0e862-4455-4d6d-bb08-1ed232dd903d)

---

This is assuming that you are using NVIDIA drivers. If this isn't the case, then Microsoft Answer's "[Dual Display Numbering in Vista](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistaappearance/thread/1aa0e862-4455-4d6d-bb08-1ed232dd903d)"  thread has four other methods. Check it out.